# How to calculate the distance inside this 45deg rectangle

Tags: area

What is the easiest arithmetic to get the 168px distance marked in red in the rectangle based on a square which is 340px width x 577px height and rotated 45 deg ?

I came to the solution: 168px doing the following calculation:

(577px / square root of 2) - (340px / square root of 2) = 168px

Is there a simpler way to get this value?

[image: calculate red distance inside this rectangle]

Comment: So you are asking, if $a,b$ are given, is there a simpler way to express $\frac{a-b}{\sqrt{2}}$? I don't believe so. (Okay, you have $\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{b}{\sqrt{2}}$...)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you reached the values of 648px and 240px, but your left corner, top corner, and middle point from the two lines leaving these form a 45-45-90 triangle.

The two legs of a 45-45-90 triangle must have equal lengths.

Therefore, if your math is correct, 648 must equal 240 + 168.  It does not, therefore your solution is incorrect.

If you know for sure the one side is 648, then simply, 648 - 240 for 408.